# Appending Date in SQL Function

Tags: sql-server, function

I am trying to get the correct year based on the current date and append to the fiscal year months date part but I am getting an error that it is not an integer.  Ideas or thoughts?

```
`ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_CS_IssuedMODs] (@currentDate DATE)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(SELECT cs.Specialist, CASE WHEN COUNT(mn.mod_number_id) IS NULL 
        THEN 0 ELSE COUNT(mn.mod_number_id) END AS IssuedMODS, 
        cs.user_certificateSerialNumber
FROM    dbo.tbl_modificationNumbers AS mn RIGHT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.vw_ContractSpecialists AS cs ON mn.mod_specialist_id =     cs.user_certificateSerialNumber
WHERE    (mn.statusID = 10)  AND effective_date between '10/1/'+DATEPART(YEAR,@currentDate) 
                            + CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, @CurrentDate) >= 10 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END AND '09/30/'+DATEPART    (YEAR,@currentDate)                               
GROUP BY cs.Specialist, cs.user_certificateSerialNumber`
```

Comment: This doesn't look like ANSI SQL, please tag with the dbms you're using.

Comment: For that specific error change to `'09/30/'+ CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,@currentDate) AS VARCHAR(4))`

Comment: Please edit your question and provide some examples of data and what you want to accomplish.  Your code is very difficult to interpret.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using. 2014 has DATEFROMPARTS which would help.

Answer (score 1):

lets create some variables for testing:

```
DECLARE @currentDate DATETIME = '4/2/2014'

DECLARE @FiscalYearStart DATETIME
DECLARE @FiscalYearEnd DATETIME
```

Now we are going to check whether the current date is before or after October 1 and if so, we are going to start the fiscal year using the previous year, otherwise we are in the new fiscal year.

```
SELECT @FiscalYearStart = 
(
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, @currentDate) < 10 THEN 
            DATEADD(MONTH,9, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, @currentDate) - 1, 0))
        ELSE
            DATEADD(MONTH,9, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, @currentDate), 0))
    END
),
@FiscalYearEnd = 
(
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, @currentDate) < 10 THEN 
            DATEADD(MONTH,9, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, @currentDate), 0))
        ELSE
            DATEADD(MONTH,9, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, @currentDate) + 1, 0))
    END
)

SELECT @FiscalYearStart As FiscalYearStart, @FiscalYearEnd As FiscalYearEnd
```

Output:

```
FiscalYearStart         FiscalYearEnd
2013-10-01 00:00:00.000 2014-10-01 00:00:00.000
```

Now you can use `effective_date >= @FiscalYearStart AND effective_date < @FiscalYearEnd` in your query to pull the correct data for the year.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `datepart()` use either `datename()`.  Or, do an explicit `cast()` to a string.

The `+` operator is overloaded in SQL Server.  When it encounters a number, it is treated as addition -- and you can't add strings.

I can't figure out what your code is supposed to be doing.  There are probably better ways to accomplish what you want.  For starters, you should use ISO standard date formats (YYYYMMDD or YYYY-MM-DD) for constants.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_CS_IssuedMODs] (@currentDate DATE)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(SELECT cs.Specialist, CASE WHEN COUNT(mn.mod_number_id) IS NULL 
    THEN 0 ELSE COUNT(mn.mod_number_id) END AS IssuedMODS, 
    cs.user_certificateSerialNumber
FROM    dbo.tbl_modificationNumbers AS mn RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.vw_ContractSpecialists AS cs ON mn.mod_specialist_id = cs.user_certificateSerialNumber
WHERE    (mn.statusID = 10)  AND effective_date between Cast(DATEPART(YEAR, DateAdd(Year, CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, @CurrentDate) >= 10 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END, @currentDate)) as varchar) + '-10-1' 
                        AND Cast(DATEPART(YEAR,@currentDate) as varchar) + '-09-30'                               
GROUP BY cs.Specialist, cs.user_certificateSerialNumber
```